# Break summation into component summations

Tags: sum

I'm trying to compute analytically the following infinite sum:

```
Sum[Exp[-x^2] HermiteH[10,x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

In version 13.1, the output is unevaluated, but with the Hermite polynomial expanded (to 10th order).

However, if I separately "by hand" perform the summation for each of those Hermite terms individually, each is evaluated (to elliptic theta functions), which of course I can then sum and `FullSimplify`.

How can I efficiently evaluate *analytically* the full sum, particularly when I have even higher-order Hermite polynomials (multiplied by the Gaussian), without resorting to splitting the summation "by hand"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you meant

```
s = Sum[Exp[-x^2] HermiteH[10, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
Sum[#, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] & /@ Expand[s[[1]]];
FullSimplify[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

```
f[k_?IntegerQ] := If[OddQ[k], 0, Total[Sum[Exp[-x^2] #, {x, -∞, ∞}] & /@
  List @@ HermiteH[k, x]] // Simplify]

f[10]
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Ah... both your and Nasser's solutions are sufficient... thanks ($+1$s).  I find Nasser's just a teeny bit more elegant.

Comment: No disagreement from me.